# how to remove notification in receive SMS in android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I write sms application.this app adds contacts in database,and when  recieved  sms ,it deleted in inbox and added for my database,

my code:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

db_contact = new DatabaseContact(context);
db_sms = new DatabaseSMS(context);

Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "", str2 = "";
if (bundle != null) {
    // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

        str = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

        str2 = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    }
    // ---display the new SMS message---
    Log.e("", str2);
    db = db_contact.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursors = db.rawQuery("select * from " + db_contact.TABLE
            + " where tel='" + str2 + "' ", null);
    for (int i = 0; i < cursors.getCount(); i++) {
        cursors.moveToNext();

        String name = cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String tel = cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("tel"));
        Log.e("Add to database :   ", name + " ,tel " + tel);
        db_sms.AddRow(name, tel, str);

        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            int thread_id = c.getInt(1); // get the thread_id
            context.getContentResolver().delete(
                    Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/"
                            + thread_id), null, null);

        }

    }

}
 }
```

how to remove notification in receive  sms  ?
how to Manage Notification in app?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what is the question here, but if you by any chance want to remove your notification then, well, do not post in in first place. If you want to disable in other apps then you only can tell your users they shall disable these notification in other apps' settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Removing notifications**

Notifications remain visible until one of the following happens:

- The user dismisses the notification either individually or by using
  "Clear All" (if the notification can be cleared).
- The user clicks the notification, and you called setAutoCancel() when
  you created the notification.
- You call cancel() for a specific notification ID. This method also
  deletes ongoing notifications.
- You call cancelAll(), which removes all of the notifications you
  previously issued.